# Can I get a document back after I have returned it?

Tags: papers-please

After approving a migrant worker's passport and returning it to them, I realized that it was expired. I still have their work ticket, which appears valid. Is there any way to deny them entry to the country at this point?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Nope.

Well, you just made a big mistake: You approved before checking everything. The game is very harsh in this regard and does not allow you to roll back your decision, once you have given back the document.

This is part of the message - Think before you act, even if it takes valuable time ... Or just push your luck.

Also: You don't get fined immediately for a simple error - you get two chances every day to make mistakes (intentional or otherwise), and then the fines start kicking in.

Comment: I would like to remark that the first two mistakes *do* carry a penalty—the salary that otherwise would have been earned for that entrant is lost. You only earn salary for entrants that leave without generating a citation. Once the citations start issuing fines, not only do you miss out on the entrant's potential salary, but you also begin losing previous salaries.